# ¿Como hacer correctamente este POST en angular?

Tags: angular, api, post, postman, http-post

saludos veran estoy tratando de hace un POST para crear un usuario a una API de pruebas, de la siguiente manera
[image]

En POSTMAN funciona bien.

Ahora en angular no se porque no funcio, por el menot solo estoy imprimiendo la respuesta que me da.

Primeramente he creado una clase UsuarioLogin, para modear la data

```
export class UsuarioLogin {
  nombre?: string;
  apellido?: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
}
```

Y he creado un servicio para realizar el POST

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { UsuarioLogin } from '../../models/usuario.login';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LogginService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }   


  createUser(usuario: UsuarioLogin) {

    const URL = 'http://www.calypsotech.it/api/register';

    const json = {
      name: usuario.nombre,
      surname: usuario.apellido,
      email: usuario.email,
      password: usuario.password
    };    

    return this.http.post(URL, json);
  }     

}
```

Y este servicio lo estoy llamando desde el componente para registro de usuario

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UsuarioLogin } from '../models/usuario.login';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { LogginService } from '../services/services.index';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {

  usuario: UsuarioLogin;
  terminos = false;

  constructor(private login: LogginService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.usuario = new UsuarioLogin();
  }


  enviar(form: NgForm) {

    if (form.invalid) {
      return;
    }

    this.login.createUser(this.usuario).subscribe(resp => {
      console.log(resp);
    });    
  }   
}
```

Y este es el html donde estoy pasando la data

```
<!-- inicio formulario -->
      <form class="form-horizontal form-material" id="loginform" (ngSubmit)="enviar(f)" #f="ngForm">

        <p class="box-title m-t-40 m-b-0 mb-5 h1">Registrate ahora</p>

        <div class="form-group m-t-20">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" required minlength="2" placeholder="Nombre" [(ngModel)]="usuario.nombre"
              name="nombre">
              <span class="text-danger animated fadeIn" *ngIf="f.submitted && f.controls['nombre'].errors">
                Es necesario introducir un nombre</span>
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group m-t-20">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" required minlength="2" placeholder="Apellido" [(ngModel)]="usuario.apellido"
              name="apellido">
          </div>
          <span class="text-danger animated fadeIn"  *ngIf="f.submitted && f.controls['apellido'].errors">
            Es necesario introducir un Apellido</span>
        </div>



        <div class="form-group ">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" required email placeholder="Correo" [(ngModel)]="usuario.email"
              name="email">
          </div>
          <span class="text-danger animated fadeIn" *ngIf="f.submitted && f.controls['email'].errors">
            Email es un campo necesario</span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group ">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <input class="form-control" type="password" required minlength="5" placeholder="Contraseña"
              [(ngModel)]="usuario.password" name="password">
          </div>

          <span class="text-danger animated fadeIn" *ngIf="f.submitted && f.controls['password'].errors">
            Necesita al menos 5 caracteres
          </span>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary p-t-0">
              <input id="checkbox-signup" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="terminos" name="terminos">
              <label for="checkbox-signup"> Estoy de acuerdo con los <a href="#/terminos">términos</a></label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group text-center m-t-20">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-rounded btn-lg btn-block text-uppercase waves-effect waves-light"
            [disabled]="!terminos" type="submit">Registrarme</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group m-b-0">
          <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
            <p>¿Tienes una cuenta? <a href="#/login" class="text-info m-l-5"><b>Ingresa ahora</b></a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Cuando hago el POST me devuelve el siguiente error

```
zone-evergreen.js:2845 POST http://www.calypsotech.it/api/register 500 (Internal Server Error)

HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 500, statusText: "Internal Server Error", url: "http://www.calypsotech.it/api/register", ok: false, …}
```

No me parece que sea error del servidor la verdad en postman me funciona bien.

Me pueden ayudar Por favor?
actualizacion, habia olvidado agregar el

```
import { HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
```

pero dando un error igualmente

Comment: Me late que el error es porque el usuario ya está registrado, ¿qué errores te da en el backend?

Comment: Hola @fredyfx , no es por eso el error ya probe con muchos otros correos y nada, el unico mensaje de utilidad que me error es "json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given"

Comment: segui el consejo de Roberto y cambie el metodoa a  createUser(usuario: UsuarioLogin) {

    const URL = 'http://www.calypsotech.it/api/register';

    const datos = {
      name: usuario.nombre,
      surname: usuario.apellido,
      email: usuario.email,
      password: usuario.password
    };

    console.log('json', datos);
    return this.http.post(URL, { json: datos });
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el problema era que esa APi  lee los elemento que como un String, lo que  hice es pasar la data con un JSON.stringify({json:datos}) y lo tomara como String.

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo (de todas formas verifica la URL es hacia donde debes enviar la petición); te sugiero en `LogginService` en vez de:

```js
 const json = {
      name: usuario.nombre,
      surname: usuario.apellido,
      email: usuario.email,
      password: usuario.password
    }; 

return this.http.post(URL, json);
```

sea:

```js
 const datos= {
      name: usuario.nombre,
      surname: usuario.apellido,
      email: usuario.email,
      password: usuario.password
    }; 

return this.http.post(URL, {json: datos});
```

Comment: Segui tu consejo y cambie el metodo a como lo pusiste pero igualmente tengo el mismo error, en la consolo creo unico mensaje que da un poco de informacion es este "json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given"